# Why does a DC voltage float with respect to ground?

Tags: multimeter

What is the reason for a floating DC voltage?  Why does it start from half of the output voltage?

Example: We have 1300 V

Connect one multimeter probe to positive and the other probe to ground.

The reading shown on the multimeter is approximately 650 V (1300V/2) and dropping continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there's no direct connection between the 1.3kV voltage source and ground, there is capacitive coupling, shown by C1 and C2 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC2oGr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming those "parasitic" or "environmental" capacitances are roughly equal, they form a potential divider, sharing the total potential difference between them. Therefore each capacitor is charged up to roughly half the total potential difference.

Then by attaching a voltmeter across either one, (C1 here, when SW1 closes), that capacitor begins discharging via the internal resistance of the voltmeter, represented by R1.

The voltmeter will therefore initially show about half the potential difference, 600V or so, diminishing towards zero as C1 discharges.